# Hibernate deleting related tables using delete HQL?

Tags: hibernate, cascading-deletes

I am new to hibernate.
This is my master visaInquiry bean mapping that has many one-to-many and many-to many relation mapping through hibernate. Now to delete the record I am using this query

```
Transaction ts=session.beginTransaction();
                String hql="delete from VisaInquiry inq where inquiryId="+inqId;
                Query query=session.createQuery(hql);
                query.executeUpdate();
                ts.commit();
```

But problem is that it only delete records from the main table.And all the data on other tables remain as it is. I want to delete all the records from all related foreign table..Please Help?

```
    <id name="inquiryId" column="inquiryId">
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>        
    <property name="inquiryDate" type="date" column="inquiryDate"></property>
    <property name="name" type="string" column="name"></property>
    <property name="countryPreference" type="string" column="countryPreference"></property>
    <property name="address" type="string" column="address"></property>
    <property name="pnumberHome" type="string" column="pnumberHome"></property>
    <property name="pnumberResi" type="string" column="pnumberResi"></property>
    <property name="email" type="string" column="email"></property>
    <property name="dob" type="date" column="dob"></property>
    <property name="englishAblity" type="string" column="englishAblity"></property>
    <property name="ieltsScore" type="string" column="ieltsScore"></property>

    <property name="refusedVisa" type="string" column="refusedVisa"></property>
    <property name="refusedCountry" type="string" column="refusedCountry"></property>
    <property name="refusedTypeOfVisa" type="string" column="refusedTypeOfVisa"></property>

    <property name="relativeAbroad" type="string" column="relativeAbroad"></property>
    <property name="relativeCountry" type="string" column="relativeCountry"></property>
    <property name="relativeStatus" type="string" column="relativeStatus"></property>

    <property name="travellAbroad" type="string" column="travellAbroad"></property>
    <property name="travleCountry" type="string" column="travleCountry"></property>
    <property name="travelCountryVisaType" type="string" column="travelCountryVisaType"></property>

    <property name="prefLevelCourse" type="string" column="prefLevelCourse"></property>
    <property name="counselBy" type="string" column="counselBy"></property>
    <property name="comeToKnow" type="string" column="comeToKnow"></property>

    <property name="counselState" type="string" column="counselState"></property>
    <property name="remarks" type="string" column="remarks"></property>

    <set name="eduList" table="visaInquiry_education"   cascade="persist" lazy="false">
        <key column="inquiryId"></key>

        <many-to-many class="com.aems.beans.EducationQualification" column="educationId" unique="true"></many-to-many>
    </set>


    <set name="expList" table="visaInquiry_Experience" cascade="persist" lazy="false">
        <key column="inquiryId"></key>
        <many-to-many class="com.aems.beans.Experience" column="expId" unique="true"></many-to-many>
    </set>

    <set name="childList" table="visaInquiry_Children" cascade="persist" lazy="false">
        <key column="inquiryId"></key>
        <many-to-many class="com.`aems`.beans.Children" column="childId" unique="true"></many-to-many>
    </set>

    <many-to-one name="spouce" 
    class="com.aems.beans.Spouce" column="spouceId"  cascade="persist" unique="true" lazy="false"/>
```

With cascade="persist" i get the error at time of insert.
and with cascade="all" no problem at time of insert but when i delete, record from only one table get deleted. all related tables record remain as it is.

Comment: I have tries this and it works fine for me..

int id=Integer.parseInt(inquiryId);
    VisaInquiry inq = (VisaInquiry) session.load(VisaInquiry.class, id);
    session.delete(inq);
    session.flush();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this and it works fine for me..
 int id=Integer.parseInt(inquiryId); VisaInquiry inq = (VisaInquiry) session.load(VisaInquiry.class, id); session.delete(inq); session.flush();

Answer (score 0):

HQL delete queries (bulk delete) do not cascade.

According to JPA specification ([JSR338](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)), section 4.10:

> A delete operation only applies to entities of the specified class and its subclasses. It does not cascade to
>   related entities.

So when you need to delete with cascade, use `Session.delete`. Note that Hibernate supports deletion of detached entities, which is not possible in plain JPA.